# Why adding more cores to simulate multi-threaded program increases the CPI?

Tags: multithreading, multicore, riscv, rocket-chip

Hello I'm using the Rocket Chip repository with Rocket Tools and while running some of the test on different chip configurations I've found this counter-intuitive behavior. I have a default chip with 1 core, and another one with 4 cores. When I run the multi-threaded tests, I consistently get a greater CPI with the latter.

Increasing the size of the data to process to reduce the percentage of time of overhead because of the thread calls doesn't change the result.

The verbose console text when emulating shows that all four cores are active so it's not only 1 core executing.

Could someone explain why am I getting this result?

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

The default one is:

```
class DefaultConfig extends Config(new WithNBigCores(1) ++ new WithCoherentBusTopology ++ new BaseConfig)
```

The 4 core one is:

```
class FourBigCoresConfig extends Config(new WithNBigCores(4) ++ new WithCoherentBusTopology ++ new BaseConfig)
```

The base config:

```
class BaseConfig extends Config( new WithDefaultMemPort() ++

new WithDefaultMMIOPort() ++

new WithDefaultSlavePort() ++ 

new WithTimebase(BigInt(1000000)) ++ // 1 MHz 

new WithDTS("freechips,rocketchip-unknown", Nil) ++ 

new WithNExtTopInterrupts(2) ++ new BaseSubsystemConfig() )
```

Comment: What are the other differences between the 1 core and 4 core?

Comment: I added the configurations as they are in the scala file to the question text. The only difference is the number of cores.